# How to use sort&compressed reference index of the latex nar (Nucleic Acids Research) template?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am trying to create a sort&compressed reference index number in my article, such as [1],[2],[3]===>[1-3]. I change the first code `\documentclass[center,fleqn,sort&compress]{NAR}`, it can not work.

What should I do to use sort&compressed reference index of the latex nar (Nucleic Acids Research) template.

Comment: The nar tex template is download from Nar (Nucleic Acids Research) web site or Overleaf template

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please add extra information by editing your question, rather than adding a comment.  Also please provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates the problem.  Otherwise we have to guess too much about your set-up.

Comment: What happens if you add the instruction `\setcitestyle{numbers,sort&compress}` to the preamble of your document and perform a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more)?